# Unable to query mongodb by date

Tags: mongodb, datetime

I have adopted `spring-data-mongo` for a while now but I hit a blocker when I need to `fetch` data regularly ,say every `20 seconds`. I use ISODate Object so it's of the form `ISODate("2013-08-09T05:51:16.140Z")`.

Below is a sample document

```
{
 "_id": "fffd8e68-e81a-4835-ac5c-ef532291584b",
 "_class": "net.publichealth.edowmis.datalayer.models.Post",
 "userID": "09258b84-6d09-4977-a0f1-4e59b963221f",
 "dateCreated": ISODate("2013-08-09T06:29:07.413Z"),
 "lastModified": ISODate("2013-08-09T06:29:07.413Z"),

}
```

I would like to query the database to find fetch all entries at the time : `2013-08-09 06:29:07` but non of the queries below worked. I have tried these queries in `mongo shell` (ubuntu terminal) and `rockmongo` and `intellij mongo` plugin

```
// rock mongo on post collection
   { 
     "dateCreated" : new ISODate("2013-08-09T06:29:07")
   } 

   { 
     "dateCreated" : new ISODate("2013-08-09 06:29:07")
   } 

   { 
     "dateCreated" : new ISODate("2013-08-09")
   } 

   // terminal and intelliJ
   db.post.find({"dateCreated":new ISODate("2013-08-09T06:29:07")}) // did all the combination above.
```

No Result :(

I can't find the catch. Kindly have a look at it for me

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't forget the `Z`.  That is the ISO8601 indicator for "zulu time", which is another way of saying "UTC" or "GMT".  Without it, you are just representing an "unspecified" time, or in other words - a calendar position that is not a distinct moment in time because you didn't indicate how it relates to UTC.  (I am not sure if Mongo will allow those or not.)

Secondly, it looks like you are trying do an exact equality match.  The value in the database has decimals, but the value you're querying does not.  So they will never match because they are not the same value.

You might instead want to do a range query.  For example, you might do this:

```
db.post.find({"dateCreated": {"$gte": new ISODate("2013-08-09T06:29:07Z"),
                              "$lt":  new ISODate("2013-08-09T06:29:08Z")}})
```

See also [this documentation](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/).

Comment: Great, you are the man!! thanks again. If you are familiar with spring-data can you add to your answer the best way to form java date object to get a result by range as you did? Should JodaTime be considered?

Comment: IMHO - Joda Time should *always* be considered, but that doesn't mean it's *required*.  Not sure I follow the rest of your comment, but it sounds like it should be a new question with supporting details.

Comment: OK thanks, I will cook something on my own, if it still doesn't work , I will create a post then.